# how to fix "Could not instantiate mail function" error using phpmailer without SMTP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer without SMTP to send email from my website hosted at namecheap. Code is shown below. I am getting the error "Could not instantiate mail function." I have read out many thread here but I am unable to get my issue solved. Need help, Thanks

I have tried using

```
 $mail->From = $email;
 $mail->FromName = $name;
```

instead of `$mail->SetFrom($email, $name);` and vice versa.
also with and without `$mail->addReplyTo()` function.

```php
    <?php
    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1; //for debugging
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $no_of_people = $_POST['NoOfPerson'];
    $package = $_POST['select-package'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];

    //$mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->addAddress("umarsattar1989@hotmail.com"); //Recipient Email
    //$mail->addReplyTo($email, "Reply");

    $Message = "Some Text Here";
    $mail->Subject = "Inquiry about ".$package." Package";
    $mail->Body = $Message;

    if(!$mail->send()) {
    $result = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } //if closing
    else 
    {
        $result = "Message has been sent successfully";
    } //else closing
    } //main if closing
```

"Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function." is printing in `$result` variable

Answer (score 1):

When using mail(), you need to have a local mail server installed. If you don’t, this is the error you get.

You’re not using SMTP at present because you have not called `isSMTP()`.

So the solution is to install a mail server.

Alternatively, send through a remote server using SMTP.